# Building Eclipse BIRT from Source (Oxygen/4.7.0 Release)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3, birt, tycho

I am trying to build Eclipse BIRT (Oxygen/4.7.0 Release). But I am having difficulties and unable to proceed.

**Steps I used:**

1. Install Apache Maven 3.3.3 - since the build requires this version
2. Cloned the birt repository from Github
3. Checked out BIRT_4_7_0_Release_201706222054 tag
4. Executed mvn -DskipTests package in the root folder

**Repositories on my local machine:**

- I have a clean m2 local repository (nothing in the repository)
- I do use Eclipse Oomph to install various IDE (not projects) so bundle pools are present on my machine

**Environment:**

- I am using JDK 1.8 (build 144) on macOS (10.11.6).

**Result:**

```
Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.eclipse.birt.designer 4.7.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.birt.feature.group 4.7.0.qualifier requires 'org.eclipse.gef.feature.group 3.2.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: org.eclipse.birt.designer 4.7.0.qualifier depends on: org.eclipse.birt.feature.group 0.0.0
[ERROR]
```

**Miscellaneous:**

I also tried building for neon but that fails because the release milestones have moved and resolution fails (even after I change the release milestones URL).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See [BIRT CI at Eclipse](https://ci.eclipse.org/birt/)

Comment: That only pointed to the same revision. No further builds were made beyond that point. The correct way to build is given in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate issues in the build.

Firstly, it seems that the latest release tagged **BIRT_4_7_0_Release_201706222054** has URLs and a feature that are out-of-date (as of the date of this answer). Building this revision will fail.

The solution is to build revision:

**Update repository URL post Oxygen (1b32db99608d028b2cfabf65aa4a34a2c7ff3359)**.

Another option would be to *cherrypick* the following three fixes (all changes) on top of the release revision BIRT_4_7_0_Release_201706222054. This avoids all other changes that were made post Oxygen Release.

- 1b32db99608d028b2cfabf65aa4a34a2c7ff3359
- 92f2f74916bf6e2fa961285dcc0f5eaa7d2c50e2
- eb8c612fc0ed0547601b5d1f9221755a44730abc

The second problem is Maven related. The top-level POM.xml requires definition of a toolchains. This needs to be defined in ~/.m2/toolchains.xml file or specified on the command-line with --global-toolchains. you can read about this in the Maven documentation [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html).

Lastly, the build requires Maven 3.3.3 as per Ben Gamble [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/birt-dev/msg10969.html). It did cause me a problem initially because I had 3.5.0 (prior to posting the question; mentioning this here for completeness).

Hope this will help anyone having similar problems.